# Can't use `cout` with a class even if I overloaded `operator<<`

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Title says all. I overloaded the operator<< as everyone on the internet said to, but I still got that stupid error for an invalid operator. What have I done wrong? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class Calc {
private:
    union _Print_Datatypes {
        int I;
        double D;
        string S;
        char C;
    };
public:
    int i;
    void Sum(long double _a, long double _b) {
        return _a + _b;

    }
    void Sub(long double _a, long double _b) {
        return _a - _b;

    }
    void Div(long double _a, long double _b) {
        return _a / _b;

    }
    void Mult(long double _a, long double _b) {
        return _a * _b;

    }
};


std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Calc const &m) {
    return os << m.i;
}

int main() {

    Calc _calc;
    cout << _calc.Sum(2,2);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: What's the return type of the sum member function ... ? ;)

Comment: ...\main.cpp|42|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'void')|

Comment: @DanielJour It is return _a + _b.

Comment: Your `Sum`, `Sub`, ... `void(...)` functions `return` something...

Comment: I was asking for the **type**. It's void, aka "nothing". So a `return foo` inside this function is invalid, as well as trying to use it as an expression.

Comment: This code makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: Noone mentions the fact that operator<< should also be declared as friend in the class definition, am I missing something? Or is it because it doesn't access private members ? is it still better style to declare it as friend then ?

Comment: @user Correct, you shouldn't mark anything as friend unless they need to access private members.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **Also, please be sure to read and follow the ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.**

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << _calc.Sum(2,2);
```

The return type from your `Sum()` method is a `void`. Obviously, `operator<<` does not work on `void`s.

You need to change your `Sum()`, et al, to return `Calc &`, and have them return `*this`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile even without the `<<`:

```
main.cpp:17:9: error: void function 'Sum' should not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return _a + _b;
        ^      ~~~~~~~
```

Your functions are declared to return `void`.

Comment: @UlisseBenedettiUlisse54: why return int if your parameters are long double?

Comment: BTW, your overloaded function is called when you do `Calc c; c.i = 5; std::cout << c;`, not when you do `Calc c; std::cout << c.Sum(1.0, 2.0);` if it returns a primitive type like int.

Comment: I fixed it again. they're all double now.